# How to modify ack deadline for a push subscription message on GCP Pub/Sub?

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to figure out how to modify the ack deadline for a push subscription message. The problem is, I don't have the ack Id which is a required argument for the `modify_ack_deadline` function. The message which is being pushed to the endpoint doesn't seem to have the acknowledgement id in it. So my question is, how do I get a hold of this acknowledgement id if it's even possible?

Ref: https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/pubsub/subscriber/api/client.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client.modify_ack_deadline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to modify the ack deadline when using a push subscription. The message must be acknowledged within the subscription's configured ack deadline. If extending the ack deadline is needed, the a pull subscription must be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kamal, that explains a lot. What is the reason for this restriction? Why can't push subscriber modify acknowledge deadline if it needs more time to process message than 600s ?

Comment: It's not expressible in the API. With pull, there is a separate API for modifying the ack deadline. With push, the intention is that there are no outgoing requests to the Pub/Sub API; the only way to return an ack or nack is via the response to the incoming push request. If there were a change made to allow one to return a modify ack deadline response, then how would the message ultimately be acked (since the response was now sent to modify the ack deadline).